# Why doesn't this axios post invoke the appropriate Controller method?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to learn how to integrate Vue components into Laravel apps and am quite new to both Vue and Laravel. I'm using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1nIMGOGYqk&t=4s) to learn how to enhance an app from a previous video with additional functionality. In the previous video, I learned how to use a single Vue component to add a new task to a To Do list which was stored in a MySQL database and then to display the accumulated tasks.

In this video, I am learning to toggle the "completed" flag for the task and update the database accordingly. (The rest of the video covers editing the task description and deleting the task altogether.)  The completed flag is toggling just fine in my component but the axios post is not even being invoked, even though I've coded my toggleTodo() method the same as the instructor has and written the same controller logic.

I know it's not even getting into the appropriate controller method because I log a message to the laravel log (and send it to the Debugbar) when I first start the method but neither message is being written. (Log messages that I invoke in other controller methods ARE being written so I know that I am writing the messages correctly.)

Here is my Vue component in its entirety:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form @submit.prevent="addTask"> 
            <div class="input-group mb-3 w-100">
                <input type="text" v-model="form.title" :class="{'is-invalid' : form.errors.has('title')}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new task" aria-label="Enter new task" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Add new task</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="text-danger pt-3 pb-3 error-messages" v-if="form.errors.has('title')" v-text="form.errors.get('title')"></span>
       </form>
        <div class="w-100">
            <!-- <h1 class="text-white">...</h1> -->
            <!-- <h4 class="text-white">Time: {{ time }}; Message: {{ message }}</h4> -->
            <table>
                <tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id" class="text-black">
                    <td>
                        <img v-on:click="toggleTodo(todo)" v-if="todo.completed == false" src="images/unchecked.svg" width="24" alt="unchecked icon">
                        <img v-on:click="toggleTodo(todo)" v-else src="images/checked.svg" width="24" alt="checked icon">
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ todo.title }}</td>
                    <td><img src="images/edit.svg" width="24" alt="edit icon"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/trashcan.svg" width="24" alt="trashcan icon"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                time: '',
                todos: '',
                form: new Form({
                    title: '',
                })

            } 
        },
        methods: {
            // getTime() {
            //     //Temporary method used to verify that a fresh fetch of the data has taken place.
            //     var now = new Date();
            //     var minutes = now.getMinutes();
            //     if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
            //     var seconds = now.getSeconds();
            //     if (seconds <= 9) seconds = "0" + seconds;
            //     var time = now.getHours() + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            //     return time;
            // }, 
            deletePressed() {
                this.message = "Pressed";
            },
            toggleTodo(e) {
                e.completed = !e.completed;
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('_method', PATCH);
                if (e.completed == true) {
                    data.append('completed', 1);
                } else {
                    data.append('completed', 0);
                }
                axios.post('/todo/' + e.id, data);
            },
            getToDos() {
                // debugger;
                // this.time = this.getTime();
                axios.get('/todo')
                .then(res => {
                        this.todos = res.data  
                    })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error); //this should be logged - how do you send it to the Laravel log?
                    })
            },
            addTask() {
                debugger;
                console.log("addTask() - new task: " + this.form.title);
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('title', this.form.title);
                axios.post('/todo', data)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.form.reset();
                    this.getToDos();
                    })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.form.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
                    })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('ToDoComponent mounted.');
            //Debugbar::debug("ToDoComponent mounted.");
            // app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController() started');
            this.getToDos();
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
    padding-top: 5em;
}
.error-messages {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
}
table {
    background-color: white;
    color: navy;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
}

</style>
```

Here is my web.php file, in its entirety:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ToDoController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource('todo', ToDoController::class);
```

And here is the ToDoController in its entirety:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\ToDo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar;

class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Debugbar::addMessage("ToDoController.index() started");
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.index() started');
        return ToDo::latest()->get();
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Log::debug("ToDoController.store() started");
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:191']
        ],
        [
            'title.required' => 'You must provide a non-blank task',
            'title.min' => 'The task must contain at least 5 characters',
            'title.max' => 'The task must not exceed 191 characters'
        ]
        );
        // Log::debug("ToDoController.store() - validations completed");
        ToDo::create($request->all());
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        Log::debug("ToDoController.update() started");
        // Debugbar::debug("ToDoController.update() started");
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.update() started');

        $todo = ToDo::findOrFail($id);
        Log::debug("ToDoController.update() - todo: " + $todo);
        $todo->update($request->all()); 
        $todo->save();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is another case of something having changed between Laravel 7.x, which the video is using, and Laravel 8.x, which I am using. How can I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Any errors showing in your browser's Dev pane? Any reason why you use `_method` spoofing instead of `axios.patch`?

Comment: humm .. is maybe is becouse yout action "toggleTodo" method Its into an image and in the view cant get get the click in that image try to use  a button instead of image tag only in order to test if with that element trigger the method

Comment: In your `toggleTodo` method, you are sending a `post`. What happens if you change that to use a `patch` or `put`?

Comment: @Maarten Veerman - Because this is my first time using Axios and I don't know what I'm doing so I'm just doing what the guy in the video does, which works for him. But I'm happy to change it if there is a better alternative. What would the code look like if I did axios.patch?

Comment: @alejandro - I know the click of the image works, although I was somewhat surprised it did. When I click on the image which is shown in the first column of the table (whichever of the two images it is), toggling takes place. Also, I've added some console.logs in the toggleTodos() method that prove I'm executing that method.

Comment: @Damon - See my reply to Maarten. I'll gladly give you it a try if you tell me how to do it your way.

Answer (score 1):

After spending most of the day learning a lot more about debugging techniques for Vue code in Laravel and reading your suggestions, I've finally found the problem and fixed it.

This afternoon, I'd finally established that the update() method in the controller was being invoked after all, which was accomplished by putting this line at the start of it:

```
app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.update() started');
```

This caused the message to appear in the Messages tab of Debugbar. At that point, I tried to add further diagnostics to determine the values of `$request` and `$id` but it turned out that, since `$request` was a structure, Debugbar threw an error for attempting to display something like that. (I would have displayed the relevant bits of the request but I had no idea what the structure was.) As soon as I took out the Debugbar statements that were trying to display `$request` and `$id`, things started working.

The other thing I had to do was fix a typo in the toggleTodos() method in the Vue component; I had added this to the axios call in that method:

```
.catch((error) => {
    this.form.error.records(error.response.data.errors);
})
```

That caused a new error and I eventually determined that I'd misspelled it and the second line should have been:

```
this.form.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
```

I *must* have done something else wrong though otherwise the code I posted above would have worked the first time. Sorry but I fiddled with the code all day and simply don't remember every single thing I did.

Anyway, here are the final versions of the component and controller modules I posted earlier (with the edit and delete logic added and working); I never touched the web.php file.

Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form @submit.prevent="addTask"> 
            <div class="input-group mb-3 w-100">
                <input type="text" v-model="form.title" :class="{'is-invalid' : form.errors.has('title')}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new task" aria-label="Enter new task" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Add new task</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="text-danger pt-3 pb-3 error-messages" v-if="form.errors.has('title')" v-text="form.errors.get('title')"></span>
       </form>
        <div class="w-100">
            <table>
                <tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id" class="text-black">
                    <td>
                        <img v-on:click="toggleTodo(todo)" v-if="todo.completed == false" src="images/unchecked.svg" width="24" alt="unchecked icon">
                        <img v-on:click="toggleTodo(todo)" v-else src="images/checked.svg" width="24" alt="checked icon">
                    </td>
                    <td><span v-if="editmode == false || editmode != todo.id">{{todo.title}}</span><input v-if="editmode == todo.id" v-model="todo.title" type="text"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img v-if="editmode != todo.id" v-on:click="editmode = todo.id" src="images/editable.svg" width="24" alt="editable icon">
                        <img v-if="editmode == todo.id" v-on:click="updateTodo(todo)" src="images/editing.svg" width="24" alt="editing icon">
                    </td>
                    <td><img v-on:click="deleteTodo(todo)" src="images/trashcan.svg" width="24" alt="trashcan icon"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                editmode: false,
                todos: '',
                form: new Form({
                    title: '',
                })
            } 
        },
        methods: {
            deleteTodo(e) {
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('_method', 'DELETE')
                axios.post('/todo/'+ e.id, data)
                .then((res) =>{
                    this.todos = res.data
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.form.errors.record(error.response.data.errors)
                })
            },
            updateTodo(e) {
                this.editmode = false
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('_method', 'PATCH')
                data.append('title', e.title)
                axios.post('/todo/'+ e.id, data)
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.form.errors.record(error.response.data.errors)
                })
            },
            toggleTodo(e) {
                e.completed = !e.completed;
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('_method', 'PATCH');
                if (e.completed == true) {
                    data.append('completed', 1);
                } else {
                    data.append('completed', 0);
                }
                axios.post('/todo/' + e.id, data)
                .catch((error) => this.form.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
            },
            getToDos() {
                // debugger;
                axios.get('/todo')
                .then(res => {
                        this.todos = res.data  
                    })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error); //this should be logged - how do you send it to the Laravel log?
                    })
            },
            addTask() {
                // debugger;
                console.log("addTask() - new task: " + this.form.title);
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('title', this.form.title);
                axios.post('/todo', data)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.form.reset();
                    this.getToDos();
                    })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.form.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
                    })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('ToDoComponent mounted.');
            this.getToDos();
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
    padding-top: 5em;
}
.error-messages {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
}
table {
    background-color: white;
    color: navy;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
}

</style>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\ToDo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar;

class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Debugbar::addMessage("ToDoController.index() started");
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.index() started');
        return ToDo::latest()->get();
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Log::debug("ToDoController.store() started");
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.store() started');

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:191']
        ],
        [
            'title.required' => 'You must provide a non-blank task',
            'title.min' => 'The task must contain at least 5 characters',
            'title.max' => 'The task must not exceed 191 characters'
        ]
        );
        // Log::debug("ToDoController.store() - validations completed");
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.store() validations completed');

        ToDo::create($request->all());
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Log::debug("ToDoController.update() started");
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.update() started');

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:191']
        ],
        [
            'title.required' => 'You must provide a non-blank task',
            'title.min' => 'The task must contain at least 5 characters',
            'title.max' => 'The task must not exceed 191 characters'
        ]
        );

        $todo = ToDo::findOrFail($id);
        $todo->update($request->all()); 
        $todo->save();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        app('debugbar')->info('ToDoController.destroy() started');
        $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);
        $todo->delete();
        return Todo::latest()->get();
    }
}
```

It still needs some polishing but I should be able to do that pretty much on my own.

Comment: Not an answer, but in your `updateTodo` method instead of a post, try using
`axios.patch('/todo/'+ e.id, data)...`

Then in your routes (Laravel) it will listen for a `PATCH` request. The `PATCH` request can then be mapped to your `update` method in Laravel. Glad you got it working!